# what is "ajaxObj."?

Tags: ajax

what is the function of "ajaxObj." ? could u give me an example..

```
if(ajaxObj.... )//i don't understand in this part
  {
    document.getElementById("divResult").innerHTML = ajaxObj.responseText;
  }
```

Comment: Can you give **any** further context for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard if not impossible to answer this question on the basis of the information you've given, but: Perhaps you're talking about the [`XMLHttpRequest`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmlhttprequest) object. It's job is to send a GET or POST (or sometimes other verbs) request to the server and receive the response, without doing a page refresh. For instance, when you submit a comment on a question or answer here on StackOverflow, an XHR (as they're frequently called) is used to send your comment to the server rather than requiring the entire page to be reloaded.

XHR isn't very hard to use directly, but it's even easier to do this if you use a library like [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org), [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) that will handle some browser idiosyncracies for you and generally make the API a bit simpler.

---

**Edit** Based on your updated question:

My guess was probably correct: `ajaxObj` is probably an instance of `XMLHttpRequest`, since `responeText` is one of the `XMLHttpRequest` properties. (Or it might be a Prototype `Ajax.Response`, as they used the same name; other frameworks may have done something similar.)

What that code is doing is checking to see if the `ajaxObj` variable refers to something and, if so, the code replaces the content of the `divResult` div with the markup that the server sent back in response to the request (looking up the element by ID and then setting its `innerHTML` property).

Answer (score 0):

It's just the name of a variable, could have been called `blablabla` as well.

Judging by the fact that they refer to `ajaxObj.responseText` I would say that it's some sort of AJAX framework object (maybe homemade) and `responseText` is the response of the AJAX call.

You should look for the definition of <s>responseText</s>`ajaxObj`.

Comment: can it type like this:

if(ajaxObjmodel)